# Convert probability into an integral with respect to a distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral

I'm studying a proof and have problems with a step where a probability is converted into a Lebesgue Stieltjes integral with respect to a distribution function.

Let $(X_i)$ be a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables with distribution function $F$, $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and let
$$\Psi_n(a) = \mathbb P(\max_{1\leq k\leq n}S_k > a).$$

I'm trying to understand the equality:
$$\mathbb P(X_1\leq a, X_1 + \max_{2\leq k\leq n+1} \sum_{i=2}^k X_i > a)
= \int_{(-\infty, a]} \Psi_n(a-x) \mathbb d F(x) $$

I can appreciate intuitively what's happening here: Since the $X_i$ are i.i.d. we can shift indices without affecting the distribution of the sum. Then we condition on $X_1 = x$ in some sense and then integrate over all possible values where the limits of integration are given by the event $\{X_1 \leq a\}$.
But I don't really have a rigorous understanding of what's really happening here. Can someone help me with that?

The context is an induction proof of the Lundberg inequality for the Sparre Andersen model from [ruin theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruin_theory#Sparre_Andersen_model).

Comment: Should it be $\Psi_{n-1}$ in the integrand rather than $\Psi_n$?

Comment: Ah yes, or (equivalently) the max is supposed to go up to $n+1$ since this is from the induction step.